# CircuitMaker: part without any net, how come?

Tags: pcb-design, circuitmaker

I have a circuit made in CircuitMaker, below is a fragment:

[image]

This is connected via I2C to the MCU:

[image]

However, when importing the parts in the PCB, there are no connections made:

[image]

When I remove the J6 part, and I select: Project - Import Changes from Fuzz.PrjPcb, I get the following warning:

[image]

I select yes, and get:

[image]

I select Execute Changes, and Close. And I again see J6 without any net connections.

What should I change to be able to connect J6 to U1 (MCU) ?

Comment: I don't know ciruitmaker, so just general questions:

Is your connector J6 off-grid in the schematic? i.e it /looks/ connected but isn't?

take a look at the library symbol for J6, anything odd about those pins?

Are both parts of the schematic on the same page, or spread over multiple pages?

Could you have a space at the start or end of one set of net-names?

Comment: @YellowYeti It's not offgrid, it is connected (I don't get any Electrical Rules Check errors), Pins are passive (no manual changes made), both parts are on the same page, no spaces (same net names)... All valid questions.

Comment: project->component links, any unmatched?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, that was the problem, see my answer (just added to help others with a similar problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved:

- I removed J6 from the PCB
- I Imported the parts again.
- I Used Tools/Component Links to rematch the components again.